# What's the noun form of "insufficient"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to write something and I'm trying to say "..but this is written by an insufficient lad.." but it sounds weird.

I was wondering what's the noun form of "insufficient" ?

Comment: It sounds weird because it's semantic nonsense. What exactly do you think "insufficient" means, and how on earth does it apply to a boy?

Comment: I mean *"someone who has insufficient knowledge of the currently discussed topic"*.

Comment: @Pacerier: It's true that we often use the word *inadequate* without specifying the particular characteristic that someone/something lacks, but we don't normally use *insufficient* in that way. You could perhaps say *insufficiently-well-informed* or something similar, but probably you just don't want that word at all, in any variation.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Or *mentally insufficient*.

Comment: @Mechanical snail: If OP just wrote *an inadequate lad*, without saying what was lacking, I'd assume the missing quality was brain-power rather than education/experience. OP already said he means *lacking in knowledge*, but that's no reason to assume the lad lacks even the capability of acquiring the relevant knowledge in the future.

Comment: To be literal to your title question, the noun form of 'insufficient' is 'an insufficiency'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a list of synonyms for ***layman*** or ***non-expert***. All are nouns. Each is linked to a corresponding dictionary definition.

- **[amateur](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/amateur)**
- **[dilettante](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dilettante)**
- **[novice](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/novice)**
- **[apprentice](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/apprentice)**
- **[acolyte](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/acolyte)**

*Acolyte* is probably the least suitable choice on the list.

**EDIT**

A sixth suggestion, per the comments, is

- **[know-nothing](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/know+nothing)**

Comment: And you could soften the blow by saying it was written by "*something of* an amateur".

Comment: @onomatomaniak I edited out several that were gratuitously pejorative e.g. "parvenu", "poseur" and  "arriviste". I don't know why I can think of these snide, snarky words so easily. They just tumble right on out...

Comment: I would add 'a know-nothing'.

Comment: @BarrieEngland Sounds reasonable to me. Now you've got me thinking about this again. "Greenhorn" would be a nice follow-on, no?  ;#)

Comment: @BarrieEngland I just did as you suggested. I really wasn't familiar with the range of meanings of the expression. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

As has been pointed out, the "noun form" of *insufficient* is *insufficiency*.

But from his supplementary comment it's clear OP actually seeks either a noun equivalent to *someone who has insufficient knowledge of the currently discussed topic*, or an adjective describing such a person.

For the noun form, there are two different sets of words. Those which imply that the person *doesn't yet have the relevant knowledge* (but probably will eventually), such as **novice**, *apprentice, beginner, learner, etc.* And those which imply he *may never become knowledgeable on the subject*, such as **nonprofessional**, *amateur, dilletante, outsider, layman, etc.*.

For the adjective, I would go for **inexperienced**. Per my own comment, we often use *inexperienced* and *inadequate* without bothering to specify exactly the specific area of knowledge or capability which is lacking. Both those terms are often used of sexual experience/prowess, for example, in contexts where that meaning may not be explicitly stated. In OP's context, it would be clear that the missing "experience" is effectively "knowledge/familiarity with the current subject".

Comment: Nice distinction between one who is callow but has potential to learn versus forever-a-dilletante. Up voted.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for *[insufficiency](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/insufficiency)*?

> Noun
>   The lack of sufficiency; the shortage or inadequacy of.

Comment: Hmm I mean the noun form of "insufficient" used to refer to a person like how "incapable" is sometimes used to refer to a person.

Comment: Uhm, "incapable" is an adjective, not a noun. The same way you can say "This person is incapable." the same way you can say "This person is insufficient." I still don't know what you're looking for then.

Comment: I don't either.

Comment: The phrase "This person is insufficient" sounds to me like it could imply quite horrible things about the speaker... !

Answer (score 2):

In the context of Pacerier's quote, I'd use something non-inflammatory like *unlettered*, *unschooled*, *untutored*, or *uneducated*: the lad (most probably a very young one) isn't deficient in any way, merely inexperienced, or, if the lack is quite severe, illiterate.  If you wish to be kind,  perhaps, "wet-behind-the-ears".  I think it rather depends upon what the fellow was trying to compose.

Answer (score 0):

How about charlatan. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/charlatan

Comment: I mean something something like a synonym to *"layman"*

Comment: Well, what's wrong with *layman*?